# Here Maps Credentials not found

Tags: heremaps, here-maps-rest

I want to use the Here Maps' api rest, so I followed listed in the docs, created a project, linked to it the services I want to use, then created an app, linked it to the project and generated an apiKey for that app. The problem is when I use the request example to try my apiKey y get this:

```
{
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "error_description": "No credentials found"
}
```

I really don't know what to do, followed the steps one by one and I cannot get this working, I've started to think that apiKeys take time to be recognized by the system, but I don't think so, specially with I waited for one day to use a key and it didn't work. I'm open to recommendations if you know about another apis, the things I need to do are optimize waypoints order for a route and then get the polylines to render them on a map view in react native. Hope you can help me.

Here are some screenshots of my project and app:

[image: Project manager]

[image: App manager]

The request I used was the one listed [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html)

```
curl "https://wps.hereapi.com/v8/findsequence2?start=WiesbadenCentralStation;50.0715,8.2434&destination1=FranfurtCentralStation;50.1073,8.6647&destination2=DarmstadtCentralStation;49.8728,8.6326&destination3=FrankfurtAirport;50.0505,8.5698&destination4=HanauCentralStation;50.1218,8.9298&end=MainzCentralStation;50.0021,8.259&improveFor=time&departure=2014-12-09T09:30:00%2b01:00&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled?apikey=APIKEY_HERE"
```

Where I changed 'APIKEY_HERE' for my actual apiKey.

Comment: Surely that should be `&apikey=...`?

Comment: @Clive what do you mean by your comment? Do you mean I could have an '?' at the end of the request?

Comment: Replace `?apikey=` with `&apikey=` towards the end of the URL.

Comment: Oh wow thank you a lot! I didn't even notice there was an ? instead of the &.